# Selenium C# how to get text in IWEbElement

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am trying to fill in a text-field on a website for which the id changes every time the website is opened. To circumvent this, I look up the webelement by it's class name and this seems to work well as I am able to click on it through

```
currentWebElement.Click();
```

however, when I try to fill in the edit text box through

```
currentWebElement.SendKeys("51");
```

nothing happens (even more so, focus is lost)

I have searched a lot to see what the problem is but have not been able to find a solution so I was wondering if someone here can point me in the right direction. What I have tried so far:

1) I was working in chrome but since this seems to be a common problem with sendKeys I have swithed to ie, alas the problem persisted. I have tried migrating to firefox but did not succeed as I cannot seem to locate the binary path to firefox.exe but this should be addressed in a different question. So the problem occurs both in chrome and IE.

2) Using javascript to send the command as I have found this suggestion in other questions that were answered on this website:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = '51'", currentWebElement);
```

directly but also implementing it as a function did not work:

```
private static object setValue(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, String value) {
        return ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", element, value);
    }

// and then calling it in my code:

 setValue(driver, currentWebElement, "51");
```

all implementations did not give me errors nor warnings (I managed to get rid of those during the process), but none of them give the desired result i.e. the box keeps remaining empty which is really starting to bug me!

Comment: Using xpath might be the right thing to do. Can you also provide the html?

Comment: quite long html namely:  http://www.vmm.be/webrap/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2fcontent%2ffolder[%40name%3d%27Water%27]%2ffolder[%40name%3d%27Afvalwater%27]%2freport[%40name%3d%27Individuele%20analyseresultaten%20per%20RWZI%27]&ui.name=Individuele%20analyseresultaten%20per%20RWZI&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=true&ui.backURL=%2fwebrap%2fibmcognos%2fcgi-bin%2fcognosisapi.dll%3fb_action%3dxts.run%26m%3dportal%2fcc.xts%26m_folder%3diE28B044694F847018BEB3F33A85A36A6

Comment: I want to see the html snippet of the target element only

Comment: the currentWebElement is then found through:         var currentWebElement= driver.FindElementByClassName("clsTextWidgetParseError");

Comment: you mean this? <input type="text" id="PRMT_TB_N17E4CB00x1817ED34_NS_" value="" aria-required="true" class="clsTextWidget pt" style="" aria-invalid="true">

Comment: See my answer and let me know if the issue persist

Comment: so both the answer of Saifur and Subh worked for me (I did not consider that me selector was wrong since I was able to select it through .Click()). Is there any preference on using the CssSelector over the XPath? What is the difference between both approaches?

Comment: I don't think there is a preference or something like that. It all boils down to the approach; whichever you are comfortable with you can use that. Though, some people might argue over the fact that CSS is faster than Xpath, but we all have to agree to disagree over this. This link might help you out in comprehending that too: [http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
By byCss = By.CssSelector(".clsTextWidgetParseError>input");
var element = Driver.FindElement(byCss );
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys(value);
```

I am assuming you are using wrong selector. If this throws any exception provide me the stack trace please

Comment: thanks! this worked. I did not consider that I was using the wrong selector because I was able to get the cursor in the text field by using .Click()

Comment: maybe also for future reference update the typo (FindLElement should be FindElement). Not enough reputation to upvote but accepted the answer as it was useful for my case

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. I have used XPATH to sendKeys in the field(**FYI the PRMT_TB part of the id doesn't change, even if the rest part does each time, hence the xpath**):

```
var currentWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[starts-with(@id,'PRMT_TB')]"));
currentWebElement.SendKeys("51");
```

### OR

**In case the above doesn't work, please try the below code too**

```
var currentWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@class='clsTextWidgetParseError']/input"));
currentWebElement.SendKeys("51");
```

Comment: thanks a million, this worked (after correcting the typo namely it should by XPath)

Comment: Oh! My bad.. I have updated my code. Please mark it as answer if this has helped you out.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: sorry, I can only accept one answer as correct even though both approaches seem to work (I have no idea which is best so I am giving the honor to the fastest answerer). But thanks for the help!

Comment: No problemo.. Cheers.. :)

Comment: I upvoted you @Subh. Your answer is correct and introduce a different way to resolve the issue